# How to add property to existing class

Tags: jquery, css

I have got a CSS class like so:

```
.simpleClass {
    width: 25px;
}
```

And I have a matching element:

```
<div class="simpleClass"></div>
```

Can I add the property `display: none;` to the CSS class `.simpleClass` dynamically  through jQuery? Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

you can specify the style of the element by using `.css` like

```
$("div.simpleClass").css("width","25px");
```

have a look at [jQuery.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 11):

If I get it right, You don't want to give property to the instance element of `simpleClass`, but would like to give an extra property to the whole class ( covering all instances ) using JS.

In this case, You can use jQuery to append a style element to the head, giving You the opportunity to add additional CSS declarations.

However, I would **not** recommend this, because it causes Your code, and structure to get messy.

```
$("head").append("<style> .simpleClass{ display:none; } </style>");
```

This snippet will give extra `display:none` property to all `.simpleClass` elements existing in the time of doing this, and will also affect every later-inserted `.simpleClass` elements.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('.simpleClass').css({display:'none'});
```

Comment: But this needs to be executed whenever a new element with simpleClass is added to the DOM. But there is no cross-browser way to do it (why does anyone even need this?).

Comment: i'm running into an issue where i need elements to be hidden with display:none but i need to get their heights first. This is a legitimate ask!

Answer (score 4):

The property will be added to div if it already not exist in css class. Hence, it's always better to switch css class with new properties. Eg.

```
$( ".referenceClass" ).switchClass( "oldClass", "newClass");
```

Answer (score 3):

The stylesheet is defined in a file, and you can't edit that with JavaScript. What you could do is this:

```
$(".simpleClass").live("domchanged", function() {
    $(this).css("display", "none");
});
```

But this is neither **not cross-browser compatible** nor efficient (nor tested by me ;). So I'd propose to use another predefined CSS class for this purpose.
Why do you need something like this anyway?

Comment: Thanx for ypur answer. But i have another way to solve my problem. My problem was slightly different and this way I would solve it. I have a table where I can select columns to display. Content loading with Ajax and I had to determine which columns are visible and what is not. I wanted to change the class property, and then add a class to a loaded content. But found another way. Sorry for my bad eanglish =)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(.simpleClass).css('display','none');
});
```