# Add dynamically using Jquery a rule to an existing class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to add dynamically using Jquery a rule to an existing class but that is not attributed to an HTML element until the user clicks a button.

I tried :

```
$('.show-toggle').css("max-height", width * 0.5);
```

as suggested in [How to add property to existing class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718484/how-to-add-property-to-existing-class) but I think it does not work because the class is not active at first.

HTML

```
<div id ="toggler"></div>
<div id = "toogle" class="hide-toggle">
```

CSS

```
.hide-toggle {
display:none
}

.show-toggle {
display : block;
}
```

JS (with Jquery)

```
$('#toggler').click(function () {

var width = $(window).width();
$('.show-toggle').css("max-height", width * 0.5);
$("#toggle").toggleClass('hide-toggle').toggleClass('show-toggle');

});
```

Comment: You don't have an html element with the class `show-toggle`.

Comment: you are forget to add `.` in `Show-toggle` class and both class are different `Show-toggle` and `show-toggle`

Comment: Thanks. Edited, this was a typo in SO and not in my code.

Comment: @OffirPe'er yes, so you confirm that it's not possible to change a class in the css file because it's not attributed (yet)in the html ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to change CSS class using javascript. 
`$('.show-toggle').css("max-height", width * 0.5);` refers to an html element with the class `show-toggle`, but not to the class in the style sheet.

Comment: This link could be of helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965515/how-to-get-a-style-attribute-from-a-css-class-by-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the .css() after the .toggleClass():

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#toggler").click(function(){
    var width = $(window).width();
    $("#toggle").toggleClass("hide-toggle, show-toggle");
    $(".show-toggle").css("max-height", width*0.5);
  });
});
```

So that the change of CSS can be executed after the #toggle has class of .show-toggle. Because jQuery cannot execute the .css() on a class .show-toggle when there is no element with class .show-toggle

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p15rcmn4/4/